# Docker Compose Down All Profiles

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Docker Compose file that uses multiple [profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/).

I've noticed that I need to call the specific profiles when calling `docker compose down` and I'm curious if there's a way around this.

For example:

```yaml
services:
  service1:
    ...
    profile:
      - profile1

  service2:
    ...
```

When I call `docker compose --profile profile1 up` it will bring up both `service1` and `service2` as expected.

However, when I call `docker compose down` it will only take down `service2`, i.e. the one with no associated profiles. I have to call `docker compose --profile profile1 down` to explicitly take down `service`.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: `docker compose` commands apply only to services with: no associated profiles; or a profile passed by `--profile`. [`down`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_down/) has no additional flags to configure this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe got it so there's nothing for this? I have to pass the flags to take them down?